# Error with package: glibc-header in FEDORA 30

Tags: gcc, fedora, glibc, sunrpc

I am using fedora 30. 
In order to install [Madagascar](http://www.ahay.org/wiki/Advanced_Installation) (a seismic package), there is a ./configure code, which one test a several requirements.

there is an error with glibc-headers:

`Needed package: glibc-headers`
`Fatal missing dependency`

in config.log file I had checked the error:

`gcc -o .sconf_temp/conftest_2.o -c -O2 -x c -std=gnu99 -Wall -pedantic .sconf_temp/conftest_2.c`

`.sconf_temp/conftest_2.c:2:14: fatal error: rpc/types.h: No such file or directory`

where `conftest_2.c` is:

```
    #include <rpc/types.h>
    #include <rpc/xdr.h>
    int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
    }
```

in order to find `types.h` I did:

`find /usr/include -name types.h`
with the next results:

```
usr/include/linux/sched/types.h
/usr/include/linux/iio/types.h
/usr/include/linux/types.h
/usr/include/asm-generic/types.h
/usr/include/webp/types.h
/usr/include/asm/types.h
/usr/include/sys/types.h
/usr/include/bits/types.h
/usr/include/c++/9/parallel/types.h
/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64/openshmem/oshmem/types.h
```

I have already installed `glibc-headers` as follows:

`sudo dnf -y install glibc-headers` 
`Package glibc-headers-2.29-15.fc30.x86_64 is already installed.`

How I can fix this problem ?

Comment: You need rpc/types.h. Not types.h in any other directory.

Comment: Yes. But rpc/ is empty. That's why there is and error. ```rpc/types.h: No such file or directory```

Comment: https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/F2NRCEXDDUF6WWNPSOMXRJS6BPMTEEVJ/

Comment: Thanks. I already tried to read that post.. But I cannot find the answer. Can you help me please with the solution..? I am geologist, I am really trying to solve it.. But my knowledge is not enough. My point is.   There is any solution in fedora 30?

Comment: Have you tried to install libtirpc?

Comment: I have already installed: ```sudo dnf -y install libtirpc```, ```Package libtirpc-1.1.4-2.rc2.fc30.1.x86_64 is already installed.``` also i have installed: ```libtirpc-devel-1.1.4-2.rc2.fc30.1.x86_64 ```, how I can check if everything is running okay in my GNU/LINUX, if I  have all gcc libraries.

Comment: Can I add manually all rpc files in /usr/include/rpc https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sunrpc/rpc/ ??

Comment: You can try, but that's like a last resort measure. What files are installed by the libtirpc packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora transitions to `libtirpc` for its Sun RPC implementation.  You need to install `libtirpc-devel`, compile with `-I/usr/include/tirpc` (see `pkg-config --cflags libtirpc`) and link with `-ltirpc` (see `pkg-config --libs libtirpc`).

Answer (score 0):

To install madagascar, this works for me:

```
./configure --prefix=/your/root/path/ CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/tirpc" CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/include/tirpc"
```